# Visual Studio Always ask to Save excel file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In my code i used excel data. but it always prompt to ask save excel file

```
            Dim excel As Application = New Application
            Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\brusoth\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\R134a_Super.xls")
            Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(1)
            w.Close()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The close command accepts "SaveChanges As Object" , it is a boolean. So **type false in the brackets of Close `w.Close(False)`** , now it will not prompt you to save the changes.

For additional code, try this

```
w.Close(False)
excel.Quit()
releaseObject(excel)
releaseObject(w)
releaseObject(sheet)
```

This will solve the issue that you are facing =)